# Predeclaration of C stdint types

Tags: c, declaration, stdint

When I tried to declare some types defined in `stdint.h` a conflict with `/usr/include/bits/stdint-uintn.h:24:19` predeclaration occurs

```c
typedef struct __uint8_t uint8_t;
```

Error message:

```sh
/usr/include/bits/stdint-uintn.h:24:19: error: conflicting types for ‘uint8_t’
   24 | typedef __uint8_t uint8_t;
      |                   ^~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/server/connection.c:1:
../src/server/connection.h:4:26: note: previous declaration of ‘uint8_t’ was here
    4 | typedef struct __uint8_t uint8_t;
```

How can I predeclare those types in my header files to avoid circular dependencies?

Comment: What compiler are you using? What are its command line arguments?

Comment: Try to add -std=c89 to options

Comment: I use gcc with `-std=c99 -g -Wall -Og`

Comment: `typedef struct __uint8_t uint8_t;` remove `struct`? What it's doing there? Anyway, why would you ever do that? Just `include <stdint.h>`?  `to avoid circular dependencies?` ? How are "circular dependencies" related?

Comment: Removing struct will just cause type to be not defined. Simply if you keep four `#include`s inside of headers you will get them included circular everywhere they occurs. To avoid this evaluate them inside of your *.c files.

Comment: I included only `stdint.h`

Comment: as KamilCuk said, just include `stdint.h`, there will be no circular dependencies, because there's nothing circular about that. you may have multiple `#include` statements for the same stdint.h, but that's not a problem, it already has include guards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include <stdint.h>` is the correct way to declare these types.  Any other approach is undefined and/or non-portable.

There can never be a circular dependency issue with standard headers.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I didn't know that. But what makes them safe in this situation, are they locked controlled by some memory management?

Comment: @DanielFreeman I don't understand your question  . Declaring types does not involve any memory management

Comment: Yes, but I don't relly understand why is it correct to re-include `stdint` any where with the header file. I see that It most do something that not-standard types does not. Isn't this bad to let a `include` predecessor inside of a header file? I thought headers should be pure and restrict to the needful declarations.

Comment: @DanielFreeman  It's not bad to include a standard header that provides declarations that your header file requires .

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. So the `stdint` does include.. macros or declaration but not definitions, as it is just a layer over standard compiler types?

Comment: "declaration" and "definition" are the same thing for typedefs .

Comment: Ok, right. Thank you. I will remember to not override `typedef`ed stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `stdint.h` includes `bits/stdint-uintn.h`, in which

```c
typedef struct __uint8_t uint8_t;
```

is defined.

You should not redefine `uint8_t`. To me the solution is to remove

```c
typedef struct __uint8_t uint8_t;
```

from your file `../src/server/connection.c`.

Is there any reason you need to redefine it yourself ?

Comment: Yes, to avoid including  `stdint.h` in my header.

Comment: @DanielFreeman but why would you want that?

Comment: To avoid circular dependencies

Comment: There are no circular dependencies. Circular means, well, circular. `stdint.h` is not going to include your headers.
You want to use `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` and similar types, so you include `stdint.h`. That's its one and only purpose. That header exists just for those types

Comment: Do you include other headers ? Those headers may include `stdint.h` as they need it, in which case you can't avoid `stdint.h`